# Designing the usage of SQL service in a silverlight project

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, silverlight, service

I'm learning how to use `SQL` with `Silverlight`.

I have:

- Installed `MsSql` 2012 server, created a database and some sample tables.
- Created a `WCF` service and succeeded executing a `SELECT` query.

My aim is to use the database in many types of queries (Getting and adding data).
Is there a correct way of implementing this? Maybe a design pattern I can read about
on how to manage the connection to the db, where to create the related classes `(SqlConnection, SqlDataAdapter)`.
At the moment all the connection code is in my methods which feels "not correct".

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred architecture of a Silverlight application includes the Entity Framework.  Not to mention that it is a joy to work with compared to the tedious ADO.Net way.  Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-20.aspx).